# Optional ending capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to have three total capture groups where the last is optional. I'm running into an issue where I'm not sure how to exclude the last delimiter from the last group and also have it look up to the end.

Here's my pattern

```
/(.+)\@(.+)\:(.+)/
```

Here's my example strings

```
test@hello // => ['test', 'hello']
test@hello:optional // => ['test', 'hello', 'optional']
```

Comment: Just to show how you could fix your pattern: [`^(.+)\@(.+?)(?::(.+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pA6rA6/1).

Answer (score 2):

Use string.split

```
string.split(/[:@]/)
```

`[:@]` matches a colon or `@` symbol then the split function splits the string according to the matched chars.

```js
var s = 'test@hello:optiona'
alert(s.split(/[@:]/))
```

or

```js
var s = 'test@hello:optiona'
alert(s.match(/[^@:]+/g))
```